# Unreal Engine 2D side scrolling platformer - blueprints

Tags: 2d, unreal-engine4, blueprint

Im kinda new to unreal and im trying to make a moving platformer. I have tried with level sequencer just like in a 3D project and here it doesnt work. Its a 2D side scrolling platformer and im using blueprints. Any help?

Comment: This is way too broad for SO. You might try on UDN, but I'd include the problem you're having, "it doesn't work" isn't a helpful problem description.

Comment: Well i dont know what else i could say. I have tried to add a level sequencer - Track - Add to sequencer - my platform, just like in a 3D project, but here i dont get the "Transform" section.

Comment: https://unrealslackers.org/ .  Join the Unreal discord, you can ask for help there.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two approaches to this kind of scenario. The first one is more Old-School: Sprites.

Unreal has [Paper2D](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Paper2D/index.html) which is a decent way to use Sprites and SpriteSheets in a project. The rest of the code is basically the same as with any 3D project, since this is just a 2D plane handling frames.

The second approach is better, stronger, yields better results quality-wise but requires knowing basic 3D and rigging to do it. Simply treat your 3D game as a 2D one with a lateral camera and a 3D skeleton consisting in planes.

If you're doing pixel art, though, the first one should suffice.